# when infix or postfix encounters a "-" sign it seems to give me random values

Tags: c, stack, postfix-notation, infix-notation

in my program when I have a postfix or infix notation to convert and evaluate that doesn't include a "-" sign it seems to work fine with my 1st input text, but when trying to run it with my second input text it does some funny things when it encounters "-" and prints garbage stuff. any help will be appreciated. here are the two text files, the first works and the second gives errors. thank you S.O!

it is supposed to run until 0 is read, if choice is 1, solve infix, if 2, solve postfix.
first input file(output is correct)

I'm trying to put my input files but it keeps saying its code...
so I put it as the header of the code. Any other info needed just ask.

```
//1st input file, correct


//1 (5 + 4)
//2 3 4 +
//1 2 * 2 / (1+3)
//0

//second input file (incorrect)


//2 7 5 - 2 +
//1 3 * (5 – 2 )
//1 5/1 + 3
//0

#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define BLANK ' '
#define TAB '\t'
#define MAX 50

void push(long int symbol);
long int pop();
void infix_to_postfix();
int priority(char symbol);
int isEmpty();
int white_space(char);
int eval_post();

char infix[MAX], postfix[MAX];
long int stack[MAX];
int top;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE* fp;
    FILE* fpw;

    fp = fopen("info.txt", "r" );
    fpw = fopen("write.txt ", "w");

    int choice;
    int ans;

    fscanf(fp, "%d", &choice);
    printf("first choice selected: %d \n", choice);


    while(choice != 0)
        {

            if(choice ==1)
            {
            printf("selection was infix \n");
            fscanf(fp, "%[^\n]%*c", infix );
            printf("%s \n", infix);
            infix_to_postfix();
            fprintf(fpw," %s = ", postfix);
            ans = eval_post();
            fprintf(fpw, " %d \n", ans);


            fscanf(fp, "%d", &choice);
            printf("next choice selection was: %d \n", choice);
            }
            else if(choice == 2)
            {
                printf("selection was postfix \n");
                fscanf(fp, "%[^\n]%*c", infix );
                fprintf(fpw,"%s = ", infix);
                ans = eval_post();
                fprintf(fpw,"%d \n", ans);

                fscanf(fp, "%d", &choice);
                printf("next choice selection was: %d \n", choice);
            }

        }
    printf("Hello world!\n");
    return 0;
}

void infix_to_postfix()
{
    unsigned int i,p=0;
    char next;
    char symbol;
    for(i=0;i<strlen(infix);i++)
    {
        symbol=infix[i];
        if(!white_space(symbol))
        {
            switch(symbol)
            {
            case '(':
                push(symbol);
                break;
            case ')':
                while((next=pop())!='(')
                    postfix[p++] = next;
                break;
            case '+':
            case '-':
            case '*':
            case '/':
            case '%':
            case '^':
                while( !isEmpty( ) &&  priority(stack[top])>= priority(symbol) )
                    postfix[p++]=pop();
                push(symbol);
                break;
            default: /*if an operand comes*/
                 postfix[p++]=symbol;
            }
        }
    }
    while(!isEmpty( ))
        postfix[p++]=pop();
    postfix[p]='\0'; /*End postfix with'\0' to make it a string*/
}

/*This function returns the priority of the operator*/
int priority(char symbol)
{
    switch(symbol)
    {
    case '(':
        return 0;
    case '+':
    case '-':
        return 1;
    case '*':
    case '/':
    case '%':
        return 2;
    case '^':
        return 3;
    default :
        return 0;
    }
}

void push(long int symbol)
{
    if(top>MAX)
    {
        printf("Stack overflow\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    stack[++top]=symbol;
}

long int pop()
{
    if( isEmpty() )
    {
        printf("Stack underflow\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    return (stack[top--]);
}
int isEmpty()
{
    if(top==-1)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}

int white_space(char symbol)
{
    if( symbol == BLANK || symbol == TAB )
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}

int eval_post()
{
    int a,b,temp,result;
    unsigned int i;

    for(i=0;i<strlen(postfix);i++)
    {
        if(postfix[i]<='9' && postfix[i]>='0')
            push(postfix[i]-'0');
        else
        {
            a=pop();
            b=pop();
            switch(postfix[i])
            {
            case '+':
                temp=b+a; break;
            case '-':
                temp=b-a;break;
            case '*':
                temp=b*a;break;
            case '/':
                temp=b/a;break;
            case '%':
                temp=b%a;break;
            case '^':
                temp=pow(b,a);
            }
            push(temp);
        }
    }
    result=pop();
    return result;
}
```

Comment: `"%[^\n]%*c"` -->  `" %[^\n]%*c"`  (Add space)

Comment: I changed it but it still has the same output unfortunately. Thanks for your help though :)

Answer (score 0):

You have this code for `choice == 2`:

```
printf("selection was postfix \n");
fscanf(fp, "%[^\n]%*c", infix );
fprintf(fpw,"%s = ", infix);
ans = eval_post();
...
```

and `eval_post()` does:

```
for(i = 0; i < strlen(postfix); i++)
```

but `postfix` is never initialized...you copied the string into `infix`. Assumably you meant to do:

```
else if (choice == 2)
{
    printf("selection was postfix \n");
    fscanf(fp, "%[^\n]%*c", postfix);
    fprintf(fpw,"%s = ", postfix);
    ans = eval_post();
```

Chances are your first set of inputs doesn't actually work correctly or just happens to look like it works by luck.

**Edit:**
As it is, if you just pass a `postfix` string like `"7 5 - 2 +"` it will fail in `eval_post()` due to the spaces in the string. You can either parse out the spaces manually or just ignore them in `eval_post()` like:

```
    if (white_space(postfix[i]))
    { // Do nothing 
    }
    else if(postfix[i]<='9' && postfix[i]>='0')
        push(postfix[i]-'0');
    ...
```

Comment: When I switch to your recommendation (which is actually what I had in the first place) it triggers stack underflow in my pop function :(

Comment: Yes, you're going to have to parse your postfix input string to fill your stack first.

Comment: How do I do that without butchering my code? I tried some things to no avail. Thanks for yuor time!

Comment: See the edit...it is due to the inclusion of spaces in the `postfix` string in that case.

Comment: THanks for the edit, makes sense but I still receive the same output. I might have to just give up on this one, I keep ruining my code more and more :P

Comment: I get all your examples to work with my two changes above except for `"3 * (5 – 2 )"`. Note that the `–` here is not actually a minus sign but another character (seems to be ASCII 0x96). Change it to an actual minus and it works fine.